# How do I render an html block using mustache and single entity in json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, mustache

I am trying to learn the mustache templating engine and I have a simple example I can't seem to figure out...

Given this json

```
{  
    "targetPatient": {  
        "address": {  
            "city": "Moore",  
            "country": null,  
            "lines": [  
                "123 Main Street"  
            ],  
            "state": "SC",  
            "zip": "29388"  
        },  
        "communicationList": null,  
        "dateOfBirth": "1970-02-01",  
        "gender": "M",  
        "personName": {  
            "firstName": "Johnny",  
            "lastName": "Smith"  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I want to render this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""en"">
<head>
    <meta charset=""UTF-8"">
    <title>Title</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<H3>
Johnny Smith
</H3>
</body>
</html>
```

using this template...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=""en"">
<head>
    <meta charset=""UTF-8"">
    <title>Title</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<H3>
{{targetPatient.personName.firstName}} {{targetPatient.personName.lastName}}
</H3>
</body>
</html>
```

Was really hoping it would be that simple.

What is the simplest way to render this simple example.

I am trying to render using c# stubble library.  Here is that code...

```
var template  = GetTemplate();  //get above template
var json = GetJson();           //get above json

//var stubble = new Stubble.Core.Builders.StubbleBuilder().Build();
//var output = stubble.Render(template, json);
var output = Nustache.Core.Render.StringToString(template,json);

var filePath = $@"<user>\Desktop\stubble\{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.html";

File.AppendAllText(filePath,output);
```

Here is what is rendered...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<H3>
 
</H3>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is .net fiddle...

https://dotnetfiddle.net/92BPoa

EDIT - example changed from using Stubble to Nustache since it is working with dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: would you please show us your javascript code?

Comment: You have both `javascript` and `c#` tags on your question. Which one are you using to do the rendering?

Comment: I am using stubble so trying to render in c#.  I included javascript since it is a javascript  engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the libraries need to recieve a json object not a string (that happens to be json) as the Data.

```
var template = GetTemplate();
var json = GetJson();

//var stubble = new Stubble.Core.Builders.StubbleBuilder().Build();
//var output = stubble.Render(template, json);
var jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var output = Nustache.Core.Render.StringToString(template,jsonResult);

var hbtemplate = HandlebarsDotNet.Handlebars.Compile(template);

var output2 = hbtemplate(jsonResult);
```